# imported jar package does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am writing a class to encode a string using base64.

I downloaded the jar file and imported it into my project in the following way:

> Right click on the project library properties -> Click on the Add/Jar Folder
>   button -> Navigate to the jar file I wish to add -> Click on it and
>   click open to upload it to the library

The jar was successfully uploaded and it is visible in the project library.
But when I try to use it, netbeans says the package org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64. does not exist

The following is the code:

```
package dfqeas.online.actions.application;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;  //this is the package that netbeans says it does not exist

public class encryptbank {

public String encryptbank(String words){

    String original = words;
    String Salt = "butternut";
    String fullyEncoded;

    //encoding byte into base 64
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(original.getBytes());
    byte [] salty = Base64.encodeBase64(Salt.getBytes());

    fullyEncoded = new String(encoded) + new String(salty);


    return fullyEncoded;
}

   }
```

I am just starting to learn java and Netbeans, please assit.

Comment: What's the name of the jar file? And does it contain the imported class?

Comment: The name of the jar file is: commons-codec-1.7, but it contains the package that I am wishing to use

Comment: The shocking thing is that it works on intelliJ idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting the NetBeans 8.2 IDE.